# How can I extract a column from dataframe and attach it to rows while keeping other columns intact

Tags: python, pandas

How can I extract a column from pandas dataframe attach it to rows while keeping the other columns same.

This is my example dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':  np.arange(0,5),
                  'sample_1' : [5,6,7,8,9],
                  'sample_2' : [10,11,12,13,14],
                  'group_id' : ["A","B","C","D","E"]})
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID':  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  'sample_1' : [5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
                  'group_id' : ["A","B","C","D","E","A","B","C","D","E"]})
```

I have tried to slice the dataframe and concat using `pd.concat` but it was giving NaN values.

My original dataset is large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `stack`: Set the index to the columns you don't want to modify, call stack, sort by the "sample" column, then reset your index:

```
df.set_index(['ID','group_id']).stack().sort_values(0).reset_index([0,1]).reset_index(drop=True)

   ID group_id   0
0   0        A   5
1   1        B   6
2   2        C   7
3   3        D   8
4   4        E   9
5   0        A  10
6   1        B  11
7   2        C  12
8   3        D  13
9   4        E  14
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
res = pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='sample_', i='ID', j='group_id')
res.index = res.index.droplevel(1)
res = res.rename(columns={'sample_': 'sample_1'}).reset_index()

print(res)

   ID group_id  sample_1
0   0        A         5
1   1        B         6
2   2        C         7
3   3        D         8
4   4        E         9
5   0        A        10
6   1        B        11
7   2        C        12
8   3        D        13
9   4        E        14
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is called `melt`

For example:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['ID', 'group_id'], value_vars=['sample_1', 'sample_2'], value_name='sample_1')

df2 = df2.drop('variable', axis=1)
```